# Call Server function and popup on Broadcast receiver android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an application in which I have to call off an alarm/notification each 30 Minutes.

I want the feature like

1- If app is closed, it open the app, Call a dialog box. On click it will call a serverFunction and if MainActivity is running, update its UI.

2- If the app is already opened , Call a dialog box. On click it will call a serverFunction. Since MainActivity is may or may NOT on the top, update its UI Or NOT.

In My MainActivity.class

```
private void callNotification()
    {
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        time.add(Calendar.SECOND, Constants.TIME_CONSTANT);

        service.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP ,time.getTimeInMillis(), pending);        
    }



    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) 
         {

              }
}
```

The problem here is , I can't put a dialog box in onReceive since context is not Activity context. What If the app is opened , Now how am I suppose to implement above features.

Comment: I'd suggest using the notification bar.

Comment: Yes I am using notification for first case but when the user is inside app and then if the receiver gets message How can i Call functions assuming that user can be on any activity in the application. If you have any idea of iPhone development we can do this in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

In your onReceive place this to call your activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
i.setFlags
startActivity(i);
```

Once you are in your activity you can open up a dialog.
I recommend you use a different activity than your main one to handle displaying the alert, as it makes sense from a design standpoint and it also makes implementation easier. Remember you can make Activities look like dialogs...